# Magento cross-sels disappeared

Tags: magento

We have a shop that we are working on for a client. We took the shop over from someone else and we try to set the cross-sels for the shopping cart, they only do not show up. We have looked in the layout/checkout.xml and the template/checkout/crossel.phtml, but it looks like everything is correct. We also set the default template to look if it is working then, but also then it does not show the cross-sels.

Is there a function in the admin panel of Magento to disable the cross-sels or something else that could be wrong?

Comment: Did you check layout/local.xml too?

Comment: Hi Simon, no it is showing up. It was strange, we flushed all caches and did also do the index management, but nothing happend, after flushing the cach manually on the server it shows up. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Have you set cross sell product from admin?
If not then in admin panel Catalog > Manage Products > edit one product and 
under "Product Information > Cross-sells" section asign products as cross-sell.